# Pager in .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, paging, asp.net-core-2.1

I have added ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging from NuGet [Link](https://github.com/sonnemaf/ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging) but I have a problem.

In a controller i have 2 methods, Index and Organizations. When I am on the view of Orginizations and press page with number "2" in controller goes to index and not on Organizations method.

How to force it to go on a method I want or to extend this  `@await this.Component.InvokeAsync("Pager", new { pagingList = this.Model })` to pass method name as parameter?

Controller:

```
   public IActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

     public async Task<IActionResult> Organizations(int page=1)
        {
            var userlist = _context.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(u => u.Role).Where(o => o.UserRoles.All(r => r.Role.Name == "Company") && o.IsActive == true).AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(o => o.Company);
            var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(userlist, 2, page);
            return View(model);



        }
```

View:

```
@model ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagingList<CharityProject.Models.ApplicationUser>
@using ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging
@addTagHelper *, ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Organizations";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div class="container py-lg-5 py-md-5 py-sm-4 py-4">
    <h2 class="pageTitles">Organizations</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <nav aria-label="NewsFeed navigation example">
            @await this.Component.InvokeAsync("Pager", new { pagingList = this.Model })
        </nav>
        <br />
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 product-men women_two">
                <div class="product-toys-info">
                    <div class="men-pro-item">
                        <div class="men-thumb-item">
                            @if (item.Logo != null)
                            {
                                <img src=@Url.Content(item.Logo.Replace("//","/").Replace("///","/")) class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" alt="">

                            }
                            <div class="men-cart-pro">
                                <div class="inner-men-cart-pro">
                                    <a href=@Url.Action("OrganizationInfo","Home",new { id=item.Id}) class="link-product-add-cart">View</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-info-product">
                            <div class="info-product-price">
                                <div class="grid_meta">
                                    <div class="product_price">
                                        <h4>
                                            <a href=@Url.Action("OrganizationInfo","Home",new { id=item.Id})>@item.Company</a>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>@item.Moto</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <br />
        <nav aria-label="NewsFeeds navigation example">
            <vc:pager paging-list="@Model" />
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the Action property to PagingList object :

```
var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(userlist, 2, page);
model.Action = "Organizations";
```