# ReflectionIT filtering pagination working second page not working sorting not working in .net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, asp.net-core, pagination

I have I think correctly added reflectionIT framework but it still not works properly it actually renders the paging and filtering actually works but when I use the sorting it doesn't work, neither does the second third or any page besides the first one.

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> MenageUsers(string filter, int page = 1,string sortExpression = "UserName")
    {
            var qry = _userManager.Users.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
            {
                qry = qry.Where(p => p.UserName.Contains(filter) || p.Name.Contains(filter) || p.SurName.Contains(filter)
                || p.Email.Contains(filter) );
            }

            var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(
                                         qry, 10, page, sortExpression, "UserName");

            model.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "filter", filter}
        };

            return View(model);

    }
```

The View

```
@model ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagingList<ProjectiWebFinal.Data.ApplicationUser>
@using ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging
@addTagHelper *, ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    var user = (List<ApplicationUser>)ViewData["users"];
}
@using ProjectiWebFinal.Data

<a asp-action="CreateUser">CreateUser</a>
<form method="get" class="form-inline">
    <input name="filter" class="form-control" placeholder="filter"
           value="@Model.RouteValue["Filter"]" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search
    </button>
</form>

<nav aria-label="Products navigation example">
    <vc:pager paging-list="@Model" />
</nav>
<table id="" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Id, this.Model)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.UserName, this.Model)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Email, this.Model)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Name, this.Model)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.SurName, this.Model)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Gender, this.Model)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Coins, this.Model)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SurName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coins)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="EditUser" asp-route-id="@item.Id">EditUser</a>
                    <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="DeleteUser" asp-route-id="@item.Id">DeleteUser</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've also added the services.AddPaging() but first I did run the program without it because I forgot it then I added it and saved it but nothing changed.

Below the image of what's happening.

[image]
[image]
[image]

> Update

for all the one's that are having this problem look at the url  in my case it says Admin/Index?filter.... insted of Admin/ManageUsers this problem is caused because the PageList class by default has the Action = "Index" so change that to your action name one way is as i used var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync.... 
write model.Action="YourActionOrPageName"

Comment: yes  , you can set the Action property to PagingList object https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229891/5751404

Comment: man look at the update please i've found it a hour ago but thanks still!